# Publish Multiple topics data in different bolts in Apache storm

Tags: apache-kafka

I am stuck in a problem of publishing different topics data in separate bolts. I have tried the things but all the data processed with all the bolts not to specific bolt.

Currently I have 88 topics with 88 spouts listing to  respective topics, then having 88 sink bolt with different streams ommit the data to different bolt streams.

Can anybody guide me through this problem.

Thanks in advance